# Selenium VBA Excel Click to open form

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I'm automating data entry on a website. To open the data entry form I have to click on a "button". But I can't find a way to open the form because it's not a common button, can anyone help?

```
<div data-v-cb0377ec="" class="v-card v-card--flat v-card--link v-theme--light v-card--density-default v-card--variant-elevated type-select text-body-2 text-white"><!----><div class="v-card__loader"><div class="v-progress-linear v-theme--light" role="progressbar" aria-hidden="true" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="top: 0px; height: 0px; --v-progress-linear-height: 2px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);"><!----><div class="v-progress-linear__background" style="width: 100%;"></div><div class="v-progress-linear__indeterminate"><div class="v-progress-linear__indeterminate long"></div><div class="v-progress-linear__indeterminate short"></div></div><!----></div></div><!----><!----><div data-v-cb0377ec="" class="v-sheet v-theme--light bg-white v-sheet--rounded d-flex align-center pa-4 type-select__card" style="height: 100%;"><div data-v-cb0377ec="" class="v-card v-card--flat v-theme--light v-card--border v-card--density-default v-card--variant-elevated d-flex align-center justify-center flex-shrink-0 text-white" data-qa="type-physical" style="height: 80px; width: 80px;"><!----><div class="v-card__loader"><div class="v-progress-linear v-theme--light" role="progressbar" aria-hidden="true" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="top: 0px; height: 0px; --v-progress-linear-height: 2px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);"><!----><div class="v-progress-linear__background" style="width: 100%;"></div><div class="v-progress-linear__indeterminate"><div class="v-progress-linear__indeterminate long"></div><div class="v-progress-linear__indeterminate short"></div></div><!----></div></div><!----><!----><i data-v-cb0377ec="" class="v-icon notranslate v-theme--light" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 22px; height: 22px; width: 22px;"><svg class="v-icon__svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M21,16.5C21,16.88 20.79,17.21 20.47,17.38L12.57,21.82C12.41,21.94 12.21,22 12,22C11.79,22 11.59,21.94 11.43,21.82L3.53,17.38C3.21,17.21 3,16.88 3,16.5V7.5C3,7.12 3.21,6.79 3.53,6.62L11.43,2.18C11.59,2.06 11.79,2 12,2C12.21,2 12.41,2.06 12.57,2.18L20.47,6.62C20.79,6.79 21,7.12 21,7.5V16.5M12,4.15L10.11,5.22L16,8.61L17.96,7.5L12,4.15M6.04,7.5L12,10.85L13.96,9.75L8.08,6.35L6.04,7.5M5,15.91L11,19.29V12.58L5,9.21V15.91M19,15.91V9.21L13,12.58V19.29L19,15.91Z"></path></svg></i><!----><!----><span class="v-card__underlay"></span></div><div data-v-cb0377ec="" class="pl-4"><p data-v-cb0377ec="" class="font-weight-bold mb-2 pt-1">Físico <!----></p><p data-v-cb0377ec="" class="ma-0 text-grey800">Produtos que requerem envio ou recolha</p></div></div><!----><span class="v-card__overlay"></span><span class="v-card__underlay"></span></div>
```

[image: on click to open form]

Comment: Try using its xPath to set an object and then click on it

Comment: Manually click on the button and then repeat the sequence using automation - but use the keyboard only for example `tab` onto the button then use SendKeys. There is no button in focus in your screenshot.